# How can I configure multiple VMWare physical network ports as a physical switch?

Tags: vmware-esxi

One or more unused physical ports on a VMWare host would be useful as physical switch ports. In this configuration, two or more virtual host ports would behave as if they were ports on a physical L2 or L3 switch.

I have tried attaching the two VMware vmnics to a vSwitch. VMware assumes these ports are to be related as link aggregated (LAG) or multipathed (MPIO).

Can two or more physical network ports on a VMWare host be connected as a L2 or L3 network switch within VMware?

Comment: I've edited my question to use clearer terms found in VMWare documentation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is not possible. I have searched for a solution myself for a long time, but it simply can't be done using vSwitches. The architecture is not designed to replace physical switches.

So you basically have two options:

- Use a physical switch.
- Use a VM. Assign two interfaces to the VM, each one linked to a different physical port via vSwitches. Then set up a bridge between them. (This will of course be a full software bridge, the overhead of running a full VM just for bridging might not be what you want.)

Comment: The part of your statement `requires a lot of resources and may degrade performance` is not really accurate. It shouldn't use any more resources than any other similarly configured virtual machine and it shouldn't cause a performance degradation. People do this all of the time. If this degrades the performance of your host machine then you've got a serious problem with your host.

Comment: You're right. I changed that statement. By "a lot of resources" I meant that the overhead of running a VM for such a simple task as bridging does not seem... appropriate. "Degraded performance" is meant in comparison to a physical switch. Latency might be worse (maybe in the tenth of milliseconds, but still worse) and you will probably see an impact when you try to route 10Gbps through a software bridge...

Comment: Yes, you're probably right in those respects.